# What shoud we write before "visit''and before 'from''? The sequence of tenses

Tags: future-in-the-past

need help with the sentence

*He told me that he will/would visit them when he returns/returned from China*

I think the correct variant is:

*He told me that he **would** visit them when he **returns** from China*

The fist part, I believe, is future in the past, but I'm not  certain about the last part (he **returns** from China) , probably bc can't find grammar explanation.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is:

> **He told me that he would visit them when he returns or returned from China**

**He would visit them** is future in the past.

**When he returns** is real future.

**When he returned** past tense referring to future time.

So  I think  both are possible and correct.

Comment: coould you please clarify the difference between the  "'real future'' and ''referring to future time''?  is the difference important, depends on the context or returns and returned are just interchangable?

Comment: and let me continue: if we want to use ''past tense referring to future time", so why not "would return"  as it's about the sequence of tenses?

Comment: @ Ronald Sole.I hope you answer this question